# Julia : count frequency of column value (unique values of non- numeric column)

Tags: julia

I am trying to find the unique values of column

```
countmap(df[:column_name])
```

but getting error

```
ArgumentError: syntax df[column] is not supported use df[!, column] instead
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame` is a two-dimensional object so you cannot index into it using one index (what you attempt to with `df[:column_name]`). You either should get a property like:

```
countmap(df.column_name)
```

or if you prefer to use strings

```
countmap(df."column_name")
```

or if you want to use indexing then you have to use two indices: row selector and column selector so this:

```
countmap(df[:, :column_name])
```

or

```
countmap(df[!, :column_name])
```

works. The difference is that `df[!, :column_name]` accesses the column without copying it while `df[:, :column_name]` makes a copy. Also note that you can also use strings instead of `Symbol`s here like `df[!, "column_name"]` or `df[!, "column_name"]`.

All the rules of indexing into a data frame are described [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/indexing/).

Comment: ANy idea if this a new update? I am pretty sure I have selected columns with this format `df[:colName]`. But today I got this error as well

Comment: It has been deprecated for a long time. The problem is that you are probably using Julia 1.5 which has deprecation warnings turned off by default. In DataFrames.jl 0.22 this deprecation was removed and now attempting such indexing throws an error. In the early days of DataFrames.jl package development the `df[:col]` style was allowed as the API of the package was being shaped. However, now the API has stabilized and: 1) this style is inconsistent with the package design, 2) there is no convenience reason to keep it, as `df.col` is even shorter to write.